# Forward/Redirect and Mask URL in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf

whether it would be possible to create a redirect from page A to page B, and mask B URL to something different. If so how to achieve it in Apache.

Also Where could i find the .htaccess file, Please provide me location of it.

I know this is been asked by many one but i am new to apache.

Any help will be highly Appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to do some reading and follow a simple tutorial on mod_rewrite or using .htaccess.